# Using Powershell's Invoke-command to install .exe on remote computer

Tags: powershell

I have an .exe I would like to install on a large farm of Windows Server 2008 computers.  I am attempting to use Powershell remoting.  I have this command which works locally:

```
invoke-command {& "N:\Temp\fortify_installer\HP-Fortify-3.20-Analyzers_and_Apps-Windows-x86.exe /s /f1N:\Temp\fortify_installer\response.iss"}
```

But when I add the `-computername` flag it seems to go off to nowhere, and the installer is never run on the remote machine.

I can launch `notepad.exe` via the same command and it runs.  Does it have something to do with it being an installer, or something else?  I realize many versions of this question have been asked and I have read them, but I am still confused as to why this doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe the remote computer doesn't have an 'N:' drive?

Comment: also the notepad.exe works remotely? What happens when you invoke-command -computername server1 "cmd /c dir N:\temp\* > c:\windows\temp\remote.lst"? Do you have a remote.lst file on server1 which list the files on N:? Is N: a network drive htat gets mapped during logon?

Comment: N is a local partition, not a network drive.  That command didn't work for me from the console.  Didn't like the wildcard, then when I removed it said only script files are acceptable for filepath parameter, which was not even in the command....

Comment: I don't see anything parameters to the installer telling it to install non-interactively. Are you sure this thing is not trying to popup some kind of interactive window on the remote machine? The remote powershell server process is non-interactive. When you run it without -computer, it is using your local interactive session.

Comment: Here is the actual command that will work locally, but not remotely:                                                         invoke-command {& "N:\Temp\fortify_installer\HP-Fortify-3.20-Analyzers_and_Apps-Windows-x86.exe /s /f1N:\Temp\fortify_installer\response.iss"}

Comment: Not an answer, but I would recommend starting Procmon from Sysinternals on the machine that isnt running the install correctly to see whats going on.  Possible access violation, file not found etc.

Answer (score 1):

The invoke-command requires the remote computer to be configured for remote management. [Running Remote Commands](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx)

If you are unable to configure remote management you could use Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) for the remote execution.
[Execute program on remote computer using PowerShell](https://serverfault.com/a/83033)

Comment: I think I have Remote Management configured on all computers.  I am able to use invoke-command to do other stuff...Thanks!

Comment: Is your command structure?
Invoke-command -Computername Server01 -Scriptblock {& "N:\Temp\fortify installer\HP-Fortify-3.20-Analyzers_and_Apps-Windows-x86.exe"}

Comment: I don't have -ScriptBlock in there, but other than that it is.

Answer (score 1):

I am going off the assumption that your command in the scriptblock is correct. Does the Invoke-command complete or do you have to kill the command? Try the command and have the results returned to a variable like this:

```
$var = Invoke-Command -ComputerName <Computer> -ScriptBlock {& "N:\Temp\fortify_installer\HP-Fortify-3.20-Analyzers_and_Apps-Windows-x86.exe /s /f1N:\Temp\fortify_installer\response.iss"}
```

Everything looks ok other than I would add the -scriptblock parm for clarity. Try putting what you have in the scriptblock in a .PS1 file and then use the -filepath parm with the location of the ps1 script you just created.

This very well could be an interactive session issue but the results of your invoke-command should give this to you. Otherwise you may need to look at event logs on that remote machine and see if anything turns up there.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following:

1. Enter-pssession  to check that your remoting config works
2. Copy the exe from N: (I'm assuming this is a mapped drive on the server) to C: or some local disk and run the script again after adjusting the path? There is a good chance double-hop authentication interferes with your script.